# JQuery and AJax for multiple submiting buttons of the same class without refeshing the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my first post I am able to call PHP without refreshing the page. But I am having trouble finding a way to generalize this for multiple buttons.

HTML

```
<form action="#" class="t" method="POST" id="p1">
    <label for="t1">text_1</label>
    <input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" value="<?= $t1='' ?>" />
    <input type="submit" class="button" id="b1" name="insert" value="submit">
</form>

<form action="#" class="t" method="POST" id="p2">
    <label for="t2">text_2</label>
    <input type="text" id="t2" name="t2" value="<?= $t2='' ?>" />
    <input type="submit" class="button" id="b2" name="select" value="submit">
</form>
```

I can send the value from the first text input to PHP, but I cannot figure how to do this with multiple forms.

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('submit', '#p1', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'answers.php',
            data : formData,

            success : function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $('#p').text(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP

```
    $tab1 = (isset($_POST['tab1'])) ? $_POST['tab1'] : null;
    $t1 = (isset($_POST['t1'])) ? $_POST['t1'] : null;
    echo $tab1;
    echo $t1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a code snippet. When submitted it will **console.log** the value of the desired inputs value

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('submit', '.t', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        console.log(formData);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" class="t" method="POST" id="p1">
        <label for="t1">text_1</label>
        <input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" value="1" />
        <input type="submit" class="button" id="b1" name="insert" value="submit">
    </form>
    
    <form action="#" class="t" method="POST" id="p1">
        <label for="t2">text_2</label>
        <input type="text" id="t2" name="t2" value="2" />
        <input type="submit" class="button" id="b2" name="select" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: It does not return the value of the second form.

Comment: @cristianmoncada yes it does. Did you actually run the demo? Enter a value into the textbox in the second form and submit it...then you'll see that the value is captured an logged.

Comment: I do apologize, but it did work. I did have to change from calling the id to the class #p1 -> .t and i failed to realize that the PHP code was calling the name of the input. thanks for the help.